# Facebook email address and phone is not populating in cognito user pool

Tags: ios, facebook, amazon-cognito

I am trying to integrate Facebook as provider to cognito user pool as part of an iOS app development. A user is getting created inside user pool, but the email address is missing. We are requesting email address from Facebook as well as added the attribute mapping to the user pool to read email. However email field is empty. What could be reason for this issue? Is it related to permissions of Facebook, should I need to complete business verification or app review for accessing these attributes? FYI I am testing an account with both email address and phone no configured in Facebook.

iOS code invoking amplify to present fb login.

```
 Amplify.Publisher.create {
            try await Amplify.Auth.signInWithWebUI(for: .facebook, presentationAnchor: window)
            }.sink {
                if case let .failure(authError) = $0 {
                    print("Sign in failed \(authError)")
                }
            }
            receiveValue: { signInResult in
                if signInResult.isSignedIn {
                    print("Sign in succeeded")
                }
            }
```

amplifyconfiguration.json

```
{
    "auth": {
        "plugins": {
            "awsCognitoAuthPlugin": {
                "IdentityManager": {
                    "Default": {}
                },
                "CognitoUserPool": {
                    "Default": {
                        "PoolId": "us-*********",
                        "AppClientId": "************",
                        "AppClientSecret": "************",
                        "Region": "us-************"
                    }
                },
                "Auth": {
                    "Default": {
                        "authenticationFlowType": "USER_SRP_AUTH",
                        "OAuth": {
                            "WebDomain": "************",
                            "AppClientId": "************",
                            "AppClientSecret": "************",
                            "SignInRedirectURI": "************://",
                            "SignOutRedirectURI": "",
                            "Scopes": ["openid", "email"]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

screenshot of fb settings inside console. FYI values of fb is provided, removed from the screenshot

[image]

[image: The app page inside logged in user account]

[image]
The fb screenshots show that we have access to email address. Except the login review error alert. Should we need to do login review in order to access email?

Comment: Not sure why you'd expect to get a phone number in the first place, because that is not available for normal third-party apps. _"What could be reason for this issue?"_ - how should we know, without having seen any code?

Comment: @CBroe I have edited the question with necessary info, could you please take a look at it now?

Comment: Does the user profile in question _have_ a verified(!) email address in their profile? Did they actually grant the permissions you were asking for?

Comment: @CBroe Yes, the test account have an email address configured and given the permission to share it. I have attached some screenshots.

Comment: Should not depend on review in this case - that you are getting this warning shown, means you must be using an account that has a role in the app (admin/developer) for testing, and those can be asked for these permissions without review.

Comment: @CBroe Got it. Is there anything else that will prevent from email address getting populated inside cognito?

Comment: Couldn't tell you, I only know about the Facebook side of things. If you can somehow get the access token from the signInResult, then you could test in Graph API Explorer if this returns the email address when you make a request for `me?fields=id,name,email` using that token.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is kind of blunder, I have specified the phone number inside attribute mapping. As the user @CBroe pointed out the phone number is not accessible from Facebook. Since I have specified phone number inside attribute mapping along with email, it caused the failure of email mapping too. Removing phone number from mapping fixed the issue.